# Why has the admissibility of the Graybill–Deal estimator eluded a proof for so long?

Tags: estimation, admissibility

The Graybill–Deal estimator is used to estimate the shared mean of two normals with unknown variances. I understand the literature has proven it is unbiased, but a proof of admissibility has not yet appeared in the literature, after many years since it was first proposed.

Is there a general reason for this? I always thought that it was because it was not a very exciting problem to deal with onto itself, but was wondering if there was some other reason.

Comment: [This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378375896002029)  [that I did not check as it is behind a paywall] contains some statements about its admissibility.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks, I read the paper and it seems they proved an asymptotic result. It also seems to be the closest result we have, even though it was 25 years ago. Do you have any opinions on why this problem is still open? Is it because of lack of interest or that it is actually technically challenging?

Comment: It may be a lack of interest, although the Stein literature from the 80's was considering all possible cases. I presume it is admissible, because of being an estimator of dimension one.